# How do you render Text("Content") in SwiftUI on an iPad in Swift Playgrounds vs. Xcode on a Mac?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ipad-playgrounds

The above code works on a Mac, using the Xcode editor. However, the same code returns: `abort() called` on an iPad using Swift Playground's editor. How do I render Text() on the iPad?

I followed the directions in this video:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10643/

I found a similar question in Apple's developer forums, but no real solution:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667357

I tried decreasing the size, but that didn't help:

"I would assume based on the other question with Abort(), that Abort() is called if it is about to crash, and it seems that the view isn't getting the bounds of the screen in the live view, so it doesn't know how/where to render the view."

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ProgressView: View {
   
   var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           Circle()
           .stroke(lineWidth: 40)
           .foregroundColor(.blue)
               Text("25%")
       }
   }
   
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ProgressView().padding(150))
```

Comment: Are you trying to preview it on an iPad/iPhone? I just checked this code and everything looks fine.

Comment: iPad. Children will be handed iPads in a class I'll teach this summer, but no Macs. It works fine on a Mac. I was hoping to let them use the Swift Playgrounds editor on the iPad -- I just need to figure out how to get the same results as the Mac.

Comment: Interesting... just tested and got the same result.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Check out [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667258) - the current fix is to add a `.frame`, which really shouldn't be needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug — I filed feedback #FB9092837. But until Apple fixes it, adding a hardcoded `.frame` works as a hacky fix.

```
.frame(width: 500, height: 500)
```

However, it takes a while to load... it first renders in the top-left corner, and after a couple seconds, moves to the center.

<kbd>[image: GIF of the long loading time]</kbd>

I found that if you put your `ProgressView` inside another container view, and set the frame there, it's much faster.

<kbd>[image: GIF of the much faster loading time]</kbd>

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ProgressView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("25%")
        }
    }
}

struct ContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView()
            .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContainerView())
```